# :active problems with my navigation menu

Tags: html, css

im using HTML5 and CSS 3 only on my navigation menu and what i want is that  when i click on lets say "Admin" my childmenu should popup with sublinks. My problem right now is that when I click on Home my childmenu pops up but it disappears after like 0.5 seconds beacuse its :active? I tried :Hover and it works perfectly but I cant use it since my webapplication is for mobile devices. What can I do to make it work? To be able to click and the childmenu is there until I click on another link in my navigation menu.

This is my CSS:

```
#menu {
  width: 960px;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

ul#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 961px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
    /* gradient */
    background: #6a6a6a url(images/nav-bar-bg.png) repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#074a98), to(#05366e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #074a98,  #05366e);
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #074a98, #05366e);     
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 12px verdana,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

ul#nav .current a, ul#nav li:active > a  {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #330000;
 background: #dd006b;  
}


ul#nav  ul {
  display: none;
}


ul#nav li:active > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 961px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  /* gradient */
  background: #dd006b url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x;      
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dd006b), to(#a1014e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dd006b,  #a1014e);
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #dd006b, #a1014e); 

}

ul#nav li:active > ul li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 12px verdana,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2 30px 0 0;
  background: #dd006b url(../img/menu-child.png) repeat-x;  
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dd006b), to(#a1014e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dd006b,  #a1014e);
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #dd006b, #a1014e);  
}

ul#nav li:active > ul li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you create a fiddle for this

Comment: Does :active work in the mobile environment as it should? If it does, then surely it doesn't matter if its only 0.5 seconds outside the mobile environment, as it's for one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jquery to get this functionality because there is not such way in html or css to do this, your requirement is when you/user click on other link then previous should hide etc..

For example you can see this [site](http://www.warnerbros.com/), i think this kind of functionality you want if i am getting your problem. But it is also open for little time. Mouse over on menus.

The above site perfectly working in every browser and mobiles.